# Props or State for an editor of tree-like data structure

Tags: reactjs

The app is for user to create a tree-like structure. The tree node is defined:

```
// This is  a node
{
    images: [{x:0, y:0, width: 100, height: 100}, ...],
    subnodes: {key1: [<node>...], key2: [<node>...]}
}
```

The UI looks like

```
+----------+----------------------------+
|          |                            |
| Tree     |     +---+                  |
| Overview |     |   |   +--------+     |
|          |     |   |   |        |     |
|          |     |   |   +--------+     |
|          |     +---+                  |
|          |                            |
|          |   drag drop to resize      |
|          |   and position             |
|          +----------------------------+
|          |                            |
|          |   some options for leaf    |
|          |                            |
|          |                            |
+----------+----------------------------+
```

The left hand side is the total data-structure as result. The right hand side is for editing node selected in left hand side.

The question is, should I use node data as props or state for right hand side?

Using state is easier to modify the node data, but the risk is inconsistent, because it violates single source of truth.

If I use props for top-right component, I have to propagate drag event to right component and then prop to top most component, and then modify data.

Answer (score 1):

As long as a component needs to alter itself, it should go into state. If not, it should go into props which you can se more as a configuration of a component.

In your case I believe the node data you are currently working with should live in the top-right components state, while you move things around and the component has to alter itself. When you are done, update the source data using an update function passed down as a prop from the parent component, and let the data flow down through the components again.

The state less, or *dumb*, components that rely completely on the props they receive, and will only update if they change, should in my opinion be used for simple things in the end of the data flow. More complex self altering components like your drag/drop/resize component should handle it's own state while active.

Hope it helps!